# How can I always display the keyboard in landscape mode?

Tags: android

How can I always display the virtual keyboard in landscape mode in startup of the activity? and this keyboard doesn't fill the entire screen so I can display some views above the keyboard. The shape should be like when you open the android web browser in landscape mode then go to an input field. The keyboard doesn't fill the entire screen.

Comment: When they go to open the keyboard, first switch the entire Activity to landscape mode.  I haven't tried this, but it should work, but you would need to save what the orientation was originally, but it will probably annoy your users to have to rotate.

Comment: Actually, The activity is in landscape only. I want the virtual keyboard to always appear and at the same time doesn't fill the entire screen.

Comment: Oh, you want to change the size of the keyboard? I doubt that is something you can do easily, but, if you create your own dialog to replace the default keyboard you may get the functionality you want.

Comment: No, actually I don't want to change the size. I just want in landscape mode to disappear the big Edit area that appear that fills the upper half of the screen. I just want to show my views. Have you seen the android web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);` should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

For which ever activity you want to display the keyboard only in landscape mode.

Try this in your manifest..

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard" android:name="sActivity">
```

Comment: Actually, your answer doesn't work at all. Why you think it will work?